# unambiguous use-case for using class constructor to display in series an array of objects from an external data source

Tags: reactjs

As everyone already probably knows, the react documentation is shamefully vague and incomplete, to the point of hilarity. This has lead to some confusion as to how to properly structure a class constructor that uses `map()` to display the elements in an externak file, holding the data.

As the title of this post suggests, I'm trying to feed the primary contact info of my clients (an array of objects) into a `Rolodex,` with each entry, or client, having it's own `Card.`

The react docs mention the use of the class constructor, but use nothing but functions in their examples in the relevant section on Lists. There's a vague mention in the section on State and Lifecycle that the intregration process is different, since class doesn't take parameters like a function. How should I structure this, given my stated goals? Should I even be using class?

Here's my dreadful stalled attempt:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Card from './Card.js'
import students from student_records.js


class Rolodex extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  //no idea if or why or how I'm supposed to make my data objects available through state
  this.state = {key: this.students.Id}
           }
  render({
    return(
      <div className="Rolodex">
//display cards
        <Card /> student.map(studentinfo)=>
//do i put the map here or in the card?
      </div>

    )                                              }                                              }                                                                                                 export default Rolodex;
```

Heres some sample data:

```
    var students = [{

 Id:001
 Name: "Censored R",
 Teacher: "Censored G",
 Payment:[
 { 
   Id: 001, 
   RefMonth: "Oct",
   Deadline: "10/11/2016",
   Date: "10/12/2016",
   Amount: 1200,
   Rate: 150,
   Type: "Transfer"
    }
 ]},
{
  Id: 002,
      Name: "Censored T", 
     Teacher: "Censored M",
  Payment: [
      {
       Id: 002,
       RefMonth: "Oct",
       Deadline: "10/01/2016",
       Date: "09/31/2016",
       Amount: 1200,
       Rate: 150,
       Type: "Transfer"
      }
    ]
   }
]}
]}
```

Can someone provide me a clean, uncluttered, and straightdoward example of such a thing?

sorry for the formatting. I'm on a cell phone.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example for `<Rolodex />` that you can extend to `<Card />` in a similar way:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Card from './Card.js';

class Rolodex extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Rolodex">
        { this.props.students.map(student =>
          <Card
            key={student.Id}
            info={student}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Rolodex.propTypes = {
  students: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
};

// Use with <Rolodex students={students} />
export default Rolodex;
```